# Как исправить ошибку "TypeError: 'MovieWriterRegistry' object is not an iterator"

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, matplotlib, type-error

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.animation as animation

df = pd.read_csv('https://git.io/fjpo3', usecols=['name', 'group', 'year', 'value'])

colors = dict(zip(
    ['India','Europe','Asia','Latin America','Middle East','North America','Africa'],
    ['#adb0ff', '#ffb3ff', '#90d595', '#e48381', '#aafbff', '#f7bb5f', '#eafb50']
))

group_lk = df.set_index('name')['group'].to_dict()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 8))

def racing_barchart(year):
    dff = df[df['year'].eq(year)].sort_values(by='value', ascending=True).tail(10)
    ax.barh(dff['name'], dff['value'], color=[colors[group_lk[x]] for x in dff['name']])
    dx = dff['value'].max() / 200

    for i, (value, name) in enumerate(zip(dff['value'], dff['name'])):
        #print(value-dx,value+dx,i)
        ax.text(value-dx, i, name, size=14, weight=600, ha='right', va='bottom')
        ax.text(value-dx, i-.25, group_lk[name], size=10, color='#444444', ha='right', va='baseline')
        ax.text(value+dx, i, f'{value:,.0f}', size=14, ha='left',  va='center')

    ax.text(1, 0.4, year, transform=ax.transAxes, color='#777777', size=46, ha='right', weight=800)
    ax.text(0, 1.06, 'Population (X thousand)', transform=ax.transAxes, size=12, color='#777777')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='#777777', labelsize=12)
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.margins(0, 0.01)
    ax.grid(which='major', axis='x', linestyle='-')
    ax.set_axisbelow(True)
    ax.text(0, 1.10, 'The most populous cities in the world from 1500 to 2019',
            transform=ax.transAxes, size=20, weight=600, ha='left')
    ax.text(1, 0, 'by Developers Hub', transform=ax.transAxes, ha='right',
            color='#777777', bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=0.8, edgecolor='white'))
    plt.box(False)

#animator = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, racing_barchart, repeat=False)
animator = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, racing_barchart, frames=range(1500, 2019))#repeat=False
#plt.show()
animator.save("Most_populated_cities.mp4")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/!!!1/1prog/youtube/1/16_05_2020.py", line 47, in 
>       animator.save("Most_populated_cities.mp4")
>     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1102, in save
>       alt_writer = next(writers, None)
>   TypeError: 'MovieWriterRegistry' object is not an iterator

Answer (score 0):

FuncAnimation делает последовательность картинок, а не полноценный фильм.

Исправьте:

`"Most_populated_cities.mp4"` на `"Most_populated_cities.gif"`, а еще лучше - на

```
animator.save('Most_populated_cities.gif', writer='imagemagick')
```

Comment: animator = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, racing_barchart, frames=range(1500, 2019))#repeat=False
Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']#ffgif
writer = Writer(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)
animator.save('Most_populated_cities.gif', writer='imagemagick')

Traceback (most recent call last):...
      Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']#ffgif
  ... matplotlib\animation.py", line 164, in __getitem__
    raise RuntimeError(f"Requested MovieWriter ({name}) not available")
RuntimeError: Requested MovieWriter (ffmpeg) not available

Comment: Скачивать невесть что с git-а тут желающие вряд-ли найдутся.  Подготовьте и разместите  тут воспроизводимый код программы с  соответствующими  условными данными.  Тогда мы сможем воспроизвести вашу программу и попытаться вам помочь.